# ssl authentification on service from windows phone

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect to the Exchange service using windows phone. Рere is my code:

```
var ews = new ExchangeServicePortTypeClient(binding, endpoint);
var resolveNamesType = new ResolveNamesType{ReturnFullContactData = false,UnresolvedEntry = "aleksey"};
using (new OperationContextScope(ews.InnerChannel))
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + EncodeBasicAuthenticationCredentials(UserName, Password);
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, request);
            ews.ResolveNamesAsync(resolveNamesType);
            ews.ResolveNamesCompleted += ews_ResolveNamesCompleted;
        }
```

it ends with the exception:
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (401) Unauthorized. In Silverlight, a 404 response code may be reported even when the service sends a different error code.
{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object sendState)}

I will be glad clever suggestions.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?